# Alternative to JmxReporter in dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core latest release

Tags: java, reporting, jmx, dropwizard, codahale-metrics

Since `codahale-metrics` have been moved under `io.`. An implementation in our code was making use of the class:

```
import com.codahale.metrics.JmxReporter
```

with the dependency version

```
<metrics.core.version>3.2.2</metrics.core.version>
```

Now that, we are planning to upgrade to the latest release for the artifact

```
<metrics.core.version>4.1.0-rc3</metrics.core.version>
```

this no more has the class we were using, has this been migrated to some other artifact or is there an alternative to using the `JmxReporter` now?

***PS***: Have searched for their release notes and alternatives the over internet but couldn't find a relevant result to this yet.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After some hours of wait and searching through each incremental release notes, I could find it in the [release notes of version `4.0.0`](https://metrics.dropwizard.io/4.0.0/about/release-notes.html#v4-0-0-dec-24-2017) that has an item listed as:

> Move JMX reporting to the `metrics-jmx` module

Hence now the correct way to use the class `JmxReporter` would be to using the dependency on different module:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
    <artifactId>metrics-jmx</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0-rc3</version>
</dependency>
```

and also that the package in the imports needs to be modified as:

```
import com.codahale.metrics.jmx.JmxReporter;
```